# Quotient topology of $\mathbb{R} \sqcup \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{R} \sqcup \mathbb{R}$ and $\tau_x$ be the disjoint union topology. If $a\sim b \iff a\neq0\neq b \,\wedge\, a=b$, I would like to show that  $Y=X/\sim$ is whether or not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

I know that $\tau_Y$ is such that a set $V$ in $Y$ is open if $\pi^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ and  $\pi$ is the canonical surjection such that $\pi(x)=[x]$. I know that if I find a continuous function $g$ such that $g(x)=g(x')$ whenever $x\sim x'$, then there exists an unique continuous function $f:Y\to \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ such that $f=g\,\circ\,\pi$. Also I need to prove that the inverse map $f^{-1}$ is continuos to prove the homeomorphism.

How is $g$ defined?

Can somebody give a hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any neighbourhoods of the two $0$'s in $Y$ will intersect non-trivially.  Thus $Y$ is not Hausdorff.  However $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ is Hausdorff.  Thus they are not homeomorphic.

Comment: I think that $Y$ has non-zero elements because $(0,0)\in \mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $(0,1) \in \mathbb{R}\times \{1\}$ have no equivalence class. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes they are not equivalent to anything else, and there are certainly other points in $Y$.  However to prove that a space is not Hausdorff, you only require two points, whose neighbourhoods always intersect non-trivially.

Comment: I'm so confused about the elements in $Y$.  Are not  the elements in $Y$ contained in $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$? Why two $0$'s in $Y$?

Comment: No.  The elements of $Y$ are essentially the elements of $\mathbb{R}$, except that you have two $0$'s.

Comment: I just noticed your question "Why two $0$'s in $Y$?".  In your notation we have $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ and they are different, as they are not equivalent to each other.  Conversely, we only have one of each other number, as $(x,0)\sim(x,1)$ if $x\neq 0$.